# SQL(ORACLE)¿Como puedo insertar la fecha actual a una tabla al momento de insertar un registro?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle, plsql, trigger

Se que es con un `Trigger` y tengo este, pero me genera error:

```
create or replace trigger INSERTAR_HORA   
 AFTER insert on TAREA_SOPORTE  
 for each row  
 begin  
 UPDATE TAREA_SOPORTE  
       SET HORA_GENERADO= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  
       WHERE TAREA_SOPORTE.ID_TAREA=:NEW.ID_TAREA;  
end;
```

Ayuda por favor.

Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Si puedes añadir el error que te da podria ser de ayuda para que te podamos ayudar.

Comment: Esto es lo que me sale, gracias de antemano      

ORA-04091: la tabla PARCIALSANTIAGOSUAREZ.TAREA_SOPORTE está mutando, puede que el disparador/la función no puedan verla ORA-06512: en "PARCIALSANTIAGOSUAREZ.INSERTAR_HORA", línea 2 ORA-04088: error durante la ejecución del disparador 'PARCIALSANTIAGOSUAREZ.INSERTAR_HORA'

Comment: Mira a ver si [esto es de ayuda](http://mundodb.es/evitar-el-error-oracle-ora-04091-tabla-mutante)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes ejecutar una sentencia que hace referencia a la tabla a la que pertenece el trigger.

La forma correcta de hacer esto en Oracle no requiere un `UPDATE` en absoluto, pero sí requiere que uses un *BEFORE* trigger. En un *AFTER* trigger, no puedes modificar los valores:

```
create or replace trigger INSERTAR_HORA   
 BEFORE insert on TAREA_SOPORTE  
 for each row  
 begin
   :NEW.HORA_GENERADO := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP; 
end;
```

O mejor aún, no uses un trigger en absoluto. Dependiendo de la versión de Oracle que usas, simplemente puedes definir una claúsula `DEFAULT` en tu `CREATE TABLE`. Ejemplo:

```
create table tarea_soporte (
  id_tarea number(10) not null primary key,
  hora_generado timestamp default current_timestamp
)
```